# How to plot x^2 for [-10:10] in R?

Tags: r, function

I want to "plot the function `f(x) =x^2` over the range [−10,10]. And i really have no idea how i specify my values for `x`.

I've tried specifying it like this:

```
x <- 1:10
y1 <- x^2
```

But when i try to plot it on a -10,10 range it just looks weird and i only have values on the positive side of the graph.

Comment: Hi, I have modified your question to narrow down your question. This question is near out of the guidelines of stack overflow because it's an assignement. Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions before future questions ! I answered because you tried it and show us your trial, that is great.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see the values on the negative side because x is define between 1 and 10 and not between -10 and 10.

You need to define `x` like this : `x <- -10:10`

```
x <- -10:10
square <- function(x) return(x^2) # here is an example of defining a function

# 2 ways are possible :
y <- x^2 # just with R math
y_f <- square(x) # calling a function

# The plot you want
plot(x, y_f, type = 'l')
```

Using function is usefull because you can change the operation used inside and make more complexe computations.

Note that the above solution is lazy and that you don't compute the square for `x = 1.5`. This second solution for a plot is continuous.

```
curve(x^2, from=-10, to=10, , xlab="x", ylab="y")
```